# Layout issues in custom AlertDialog

Tags: android, layout

I have a problem with a custom dialog implemented as below:

```
    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    dialogBuilder.setTitle("Title");
    dialogBuilder.setMessage("Message");

    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

    // Set an EditText view to get user input
    EditText input = new EditText(this);
    input.setHeight(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    input.setWidth(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    layout.addView(input);

    TextView text = new TextView(this);
    text.setText("show some text here");
    text.setHeight(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    text.setWidth(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    //text.setHeight(50);
    //text.setWidth(150);
    text.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);
    layout.addView(text);

    Button btn = new Button(this);
    btn.setText("Button");
    btn.setHeight(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    btn.setWidth(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layout.addView(btn);

    dialogBuilder.setView(layout);
    dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok", null);

    AlertDialog myDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
    myDialog.show();
```

The problem is that the `TextView text` doesn't show up in the dialog if I set its width and height as in the code above. It only appears if I hard code the properties (the two commented lines), but that's not the desired behavior.

Also, although the Button has the width set as `WRAP_CONTENT`, it is as big as the screen.

Could someone please point out what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use setLayoutParams() and not setHeight() and setWidth()

Replace

```
text.setHeight(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
text.setWidth(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

With this

```
text.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

EDIT:
About the Button use :

```
btn.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

It works to me...

EDIT 2:
If you use `text.setHeight(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);` it is equal to `text.setHeight(-2);` so your `textView` will be -2 pixel height and won't be visible... on the other hands `Buttons` and other that uses a ninepatch image won't get smaller than the ninepatch itself.

Comment: Thank you! This solves the issue with the TextView. However, doing this for the Button changes nothing.

Comment: I don't know why but it did not work for the button, so I've changed the approach and used an xml file for the dialog's view. Your suggestion however did the trick for the TextView, so thank you! Just out of curiosity, do you know what was the problem with my original code? Why `setHeight(...)` and `setWidth(...)` did not work?